# How to build recommendation system that also takes time as a feature

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, recommender-system

Let's say a User was Interested in football, so we were recommending him posts about football after few days or weeks he starts watching Baseball.

How'd we go about building a recommender system that also takes recency into consideration
Or
Let's say that it knows when a user was interested in what

Comment: Just let the age of the item be one of the features then. Note that this is different from the contextual case where the actual _time_ of the day is a consideration. Make sure you are not confusing them. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Use a diminishing sample weight where the newest sample = 1 and older samples get lower weights. This way if a user changes his interests over time, your recommendations will change accordingly.

Comment: alright man would try to do that but I'm keeping the question open for suggestion if this worked I'll make sure to close it